# CUDA ERROR - virtual func, inheritance, NEW Operator

Tags: c++, cuda

Using  OOP CUDA code I have strange behaviour  with **object creation**  in **global** function

CUDA device: Tesla C2075,  Compute Capability: 2.0

WITHOUT NEW operator everything works

WITH NEW operator -> FAILS: CUDA_ERROR_NO_BINARY_FOR_GPU

See code:

BaseClass:

```
class Base
{
public: 
    float PositionX;
    float PositionY;
    float PositionZ;


public:
    __device__ Base()
    {
    }

    __device__  void SetPosition(float x, float y, float z) 
    {
        PositionX = x;
        PositionY = y;
        PositionZ = z;
    }


    __device__ virtual void setCode(float r);
    __device__ virtual void getCode(float q);

};
```

1Derivate:

```
class  Box : public  Base
{
public:

    bool myIsVisible;
    float code;

public:


    __device__ Box()
    {
    }

    __device__  void setCode(float r) override
    {
        code = r;
    }


    __device__  void getCode(float a) override
    {
        a = code ;
    }

}
```

2Derivate:

```
class  Sphere : public  Base
{

public:

    bool myIsVisible;
    float code;

public:


    __device__ Sphere()
    {
    }

    __device__  void setCode(float r) override
    {
        code = r;
    }
    __device__  void getCode(float a) override
    {
        a = code;
    }

}
```

AAANDe  finally  my KERNEL in Error State :

```
 __global__ void CreateSphere(size_t *objectHandle_in)
{   
    Sphere *aObject = new Sphere();  

}
```

IN GOOD state:

```
 __global__ void CreateSphere(size_t *objectHandle_in)
{   
    Sphere *aObject ;  

}
```

from CUDA programming guide:

> When a function in a derived class overrides a virtual function in a
>   base class, the execution space qualifiers (i.e., **host**,
>   **device**) on the overridden and overriding functions must match.
>
> > It is not allowed to pass as an argument to a **global** function an
> >     object of a class with virtual functions.
>
> The virtual function table is placed in global or constant memory by
>   the compiler.

But I am only creating the object and it also fails in this scenario:

```
__device__ creatDevSphere()
    {
    Sphere *aObject  = new Sphere();  
    }

  __global__ void CreateSphere(size_t *objectHandle_in)
    {   
        creatDevSphere();

    }
```

I know that new operator is available in CC 2.0...or is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using CUDA 7 due to your use of C++11 features.
Either the `setCode` and `getCode` methods need to be implemented in your `Base` class or they must be pure virtual.

This works for me:

```
__device__ virtual void setCode(float r) = 0;
__device__ virtual void getCode(float q) = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question , I am using Cuda 6.5 . AND THANKS it is working now ,,,, hmmm school mistake...